# VS 2017 Error C2665 'qHash': none of the 30 overloads could convert all the argument types

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2017, qhash

I use QHash for a small program.

CompleterData.h

```
#include <QMap>
#include <QList>
#include <QHash>
#include <QPair>
#include <QVariant>

class CompleterData
{

public:
  enum class Type
  {
     Header,       
     SecondHeader, 
     Data,         
     LastUsed      
  };

  CompleterData() = default;

  QHash < CompleterData::Type, QList<QPair<QString, QVariant>>> data();
  void setData( QHash < CompleterData::Type, QList<QPair<QString, QVariant>>> &p_data );
  void addData( CompleterData::Type &p_type,  QList<QPair<QString, QVariant>> &p_rowData );

private:
  QHash <CompleterData::Type, QList<QPair<QString, QVariant>>> m_data;
};
```

CompleterData.cpp

```
QHash < CompleterData::Type, QList<QPair<QString, QVariant>>> CompleterData::data()
{
  return m_data;
}

void CompleterData::addData( CompleterData::Type &p_type,  QList<QPair<QString, QVariant>> &p_rowData )
{
  m_data.insert( p_type, p_rowData );
}

void CompleterData::setData( QHash < CompleterData::Type, QList<QPair<QString, QVariant>>> &p_data )
{
  m_data = p_data;
}
```

I get this error by compiling
[image]

Where do I have error in this case. I know this kind of error is posted here so many times, but each case has it own reason and even for this simple case I still can not find the reason why? I use VS 2017.

Comment: `CompleterData::Type` is a scoped enum, and there is no implicit conversion to integer for it. The same is true for non scoped enum types. `qHash` doesn't know how to calculate hash of your key type.

Comment: @vahancho: how should I change in this case?

Comment: Two choices: 1) Declare `Type` enum as non scoped, i.e. `enum Type`, 2) Declare your hash table as `QHash <int, QList<QPair<QString, QVariant>>>` and explicitly convert `CompleterData::Type` to int when you insert a pair into the container, i.e. `m_data.insert(static_cast<int>(p_type), p_rowData );`. The is a room for improvements in your code, but it's another topic.